# Is there any way to mirror "overlay icons" onto a symbolic/junction link folder and all it's files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, dropbox, symbolic-link

I have an issue where Dropbox decided to rename my Dropbox folder from `Dropbox/` to `Dropbox (Personal)/`, but I have way too many paths setup to the original Dropbox folder to where this change has broken A LOT of things for me.

I managed to get it all working again by simply making the `Dropbox (Personal)/` folder a symbolic link, but the only issue is that the overlay icon (the little sync, checkbox, error, etc icons) won't work when I'm browsing through the `Dropbox/` path.

I thought of maybe writing my own code that would mirror the changes Dropbox made to them automatically, but it seems like a difficult task and haven't committed to going that route.

So I'm here to see if there is any other solution to this problem that would allow me to make this all work again seamlessly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you have Dropbox for dual use (Personal and Business), some adjustments are required. I had to change my path environmental variables to use the new path. Symbolic links and icon overlays are not supported by Dropbox. You would need to accept the changes Dropbox has made to your folder names. You will need to make adjustments on your end to keep seeing icon overlays as you expect.